# How to show that $\bar X$ is a consistent estimator

Tags: statistics, parameter-estimation

Can someone give me an hint with this exercise,please?
Let $X_1,\dots,X_n$ be i.i.d. from a population with p.d.f. $(x|\theta)$ =$\theta x^ {θ−1}$

$0<x<1$
,$\theta>0$

Show that  $\bar X$ is a consistent estimator of $\frac{\theta}{\theta+1}$

I know that to be consistent the limit of $n \to \infty$ of  the MSE must equal $0$.

How can I find the bias and the variance in order to calculate the MSE? Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: First of all to find of the estimator is biased you can evaluate E[X]. Can you do that?

Comment: $E[X]$ should be equal to $\frac{\theta}{\theta+1}$ I have done $\int_0^1 x*p.d.f.:(x|\theta)$

Comment: Very good so you already showed that your estimation is not biased right? Just observe that the mean has exactly that expectation by linearity

Comment: Now you can evaluate the variance of the mean ( I call it M ). Can you show or do you know that $\sigma^2(M)=\sigma^2(X)/n$ ?

Comment: Do you know law of large numbers?

Comment: @StubbornAtom is there a problem with the more elementary approach I am suggesting ?

Comment: Just to be sure that you are not proposing smth else because my approach does not make sense ;)

Comment: so all I have to do is calculate the second moment by doing  $\int_0^1 x^2* p.d.f.:(x|\theta)$ and then find Var(X)= $E[X^2]$- $E[X]$ Since it is unbiased the variance is equal to MSE   am i going in the right direction?

Comment: @Thomas Don't mind my comment. Nothing wrong with your suggestion.

Comment: i got Var(X) = $\frac{\theta}{n(\theta+2)(\theta+1)^2}$ 
so we show in this way the consistency because the limit for $n$ to $\infty$ of the MSE that is equal to VAR(X) is 0 is that right?

Comment: @lollo If you found the mean, you are done- see my response

Comment: Lollo, see the answer of @Goldent_Ratio and comments below

Comment: @StubbornAtom perfect thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call your parameter $\gamma:=\frac{\theta}{\theta+1}$ and call your estimator $\hat\gamma:=\bar X$. You are trying to show MSE converges to zero, i.e.

$$E[\|\hat\gamma -\gamma \|^2]\rightarrow 0,$$

but this is equivalent to showing convergence in $L^2$. Note this convergence is [stronger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_random_variables#Properties_4) than consistency, so it is not generally true that the "limit ...of the MSE **must** be equal zero" for consistency to hold (it is sufficient, although not necessary for consistency).

Consistency, by definition, means convergence in probability, i.e.

$$\hat\gamma\overset{p}{\rightarrow }\gamma,$$

which in your case follows immediately by the [weak law of large numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers#Weak_law) once you show $E[\hat\gamma]=\gamma.$

Comment: +1 for distinguishing convergence in MSE and probability, even if I wonder if the OP knows about this stuff...

Comment: Alternatively to prove L^2 convergence you can just use that the variance of the mean is sigma^2(X)/n and observe that X is finite (essentially the proof of the weak law of large numbers ). That is what I was suggesting

Comment: @Thomas Thanks, that's right. I included links for OP so hopefully the definitions are more clear.

Comment: thank you all very much for helping me!

Answer (score 1):

Presumably $\overline{X}_n$ is the sample mean, that is
$$\overline{X}_n=\frac1n\sum^n_{n=1}X_j$$
and the $(X_j:j\in\mathbb{N})$ are i.i.d. with common distribution
$$P=[X\in dx]=\theta x^{\theta-1}\mathbb{1}_{(0,1]}(x)$$
In such case,
$$E[\overline{X}_n]=E[X_1]=\frac{\theta}{\theta+1}$$
There are many ways to show that $\overline{X}_n$ is consistence, that is that
$\overline{X}_n$ converges in probability to $\frac{\theta}{1+\theta}$. The quickest one is by the strong law of large numbers which states in fact that $\overline{X}_n$ converges almost surely and in $L_1$ to $E[X_1]=\frac{\theta}{\theta+1}$. Convergence almost surely will imply convergence in probability.

As for convergence in MSE, notice that the quadratic error $E[(\overline{X}_n-\tfrac{\theta}{\theta+1})^2]$ coincides in this case with the variance of $\overline{X}_n$; hence
$$E[(\overline{X}_n-\tfrac{\theta}{\theta+1})^2]=\operatorname{var}(\overline{X}_n)=\frac{1}{n^2}n\operatorname{var}(X_1)=\frac{1}{n}\operatorname{var}(X_1)\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}0$$

Comment: Also, as observed by @Golden_Ratio, convergence in MSE implies convergence in probability, so that the last line is also enough to prove consistency

Comment: Thanks for writing the answer I was getting afraid that the OP would have been lost between the different contributions...